# me.visible for labels and textboxes access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to toggle conditionally visibility of textboxes and labels using the me.visible = false statements. However, it doesn't seem to function properly in the on format event for my report footer.

I tried for onclick and onprint as well but none of them seems to work.
Initially i tried the following code:

```
If Me.Text39 = "0" Then
    Me.Label40.Visible = False
Else
    Me.Label40.Visible = True
End If
```

As well as the following when i made the textbox empty and using a expression of ""

```
If isnull(me.text39) or isempty(me.text39)
```

Finally i tried turning off the visibility without conditions

```
Me!Label40.Visible = False
Me.Label38.Visible = False
```

However that doesn't seem to work either.
I also tried the nz(...,..) statements with 0, null, empty and etc as well...
Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: What event are you using when you tested `Me.Label40.Visible = False` and what version of Access are you using?  I tested these in my reports and haven't had any issues hiding them.

Comment: i tried to straight up turn off its visibility without any conditions. so i wrote the statement right below the `private sub reportfooter_format()`

Comment: Which event though, like how did that code ever get called?

Comment: on format event and access 2013

Comment: is it possible that it doesn't work for report footers?

Comment: I honestly have never used the OnFormat event, does the label get checked per row in the report or just once?

Comment: not sure exactly. what event do you use?

Comment: Honestly I really don't when it comes to 99% of my reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnFormat doesn't ever seem to get called on a report footer.  I tested this by doing the following:

```vb
Private Sub ReportFooter_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
        MsgBox "Reached Footer"
End Sub
```

And the message box was never displayed.  Though since it is a footer I think you should be able to just put it into `Report_Load()` instead so something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Report_Load()
        Me.Label40.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I believe you should be able to put an If Check in there too.